# Автоматизация установки программ в Linux Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, хостинг, зависимости

Сейчас пробую настроить хостинг для сайта на чистом линуксе, пробую разные штуки, постоянно приходиться сбрасывать всю систему к нулю и устанавливать все штуки(nginx,mysql,php и.т.д) заново. Есть ли какое-нибудь решение, чтобы один раз все команды по установке/настройке этих программ куда-то записать, а потом, при очередном сбросе линукса, просто запустить что-то, что это все мне само установило и настроило?

Answer (score 2):

Откройте для себя `Docker`, у него есть `Dockerfile` как раз для управления зависимостями и запуска приложения на чистой системе.

Answer (score 2):

У меня была такая же ситуация, и я использую Ansible для повторяющейся установки. В ansible вы можете настроить ssh (например), и все ваши инструкции по установке будут установлены на вашей машине на основе этого ssh.

Answer (score 2):

Да хотя бы в обычный скрипт записать.

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/833763)

Comment: Является ответом на вопрос.

Comment: Если только из разряда "каков вопрос -- таков ответ": Q: Можно ли сделать супер-кнопку "Сделайте мне зашибись"? - A: Да.

Answer (score 0):

Установить всю базу (sudo, nginx и т. д.), настрой. После этого создай резервную копию. А лучше пользоваться всякими панельками. Но умоляю, только не ISPManager. Птичкой пользуйся, или Вестой.

Comment: Не модифируемо же